# javascript how to accept answers

Tags: javascript, css

Just made a simple text game using JavaScript. Were I ask a math question and the user has to enter a value. There are 4 boxes on the page and what I am trying to figure out is how do I get it so when the user enters all the right answers for something like text to pop up on the page.

Below. the code has been repeated 4 times.

```
function changecolour1(textbox) {
    var val = textbox.value;
    if (val == 26) {
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    } else {
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
}
```

So again just trying 2 figure out when the user enters the right number in the 4 boxes how do I get it so it pops up saying well done.

Comment: I get what u mean , but iam not sure how exactly to try and do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var counter=0;
function changecolour1(textbox) {
var val = textbox.value;
if (val == 26) {
    textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    counter++;
    if(counter==4)
    {
        alert('well done');
    }
}
else {
    textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    counter--;
    if(counter < 0)
    {
       counter=0;
    }
}
}

function reset(){
    counter=0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Simple and easy-to-understand approach, goes well with the system OP uses.

Comment: Don't forget that the counter doesn't get reset if an answer is changed to something incorrect.

Comment: ah yes . Thanks how do i get it 2 reset if the answers are reset?

Comment: On the reset button/function reset counter to 0, will edit in

Comment: I don't want to be a stickler, but this is still going to cause issues.  Four wrong answers and the counter is at -4, you would never get back up to +4

Comment: Thanks. Anther question, this will work for 4 input boxes say? So i have 4 on the page each of them have a diffrent answer , will that work?

Comment: Edited the answer to appease Bort ;-) who actually made a good point IF the answers can be changed. Ali, not sure what you mean? Personally I'd probably do the whole thing slightly differently since your answers are going to be completely visible in code view anyway but if you have different answers on different pages you just change the script?

Comment: Well what iam trying 2 do is have 4 boxes and by them i have a question so 1+1 , they have 2 enter 2 and then they go down to the next box etc. So when they get all 4 right it will say well done.

Comment: Oh, yeah I only added one box for the example. You can copy the functions for the textboxes as many times as you want, just don't duplicate the var counter; line. For the record have a look at jbabey's answer, it's a little more elegant although both answers will work

Comment: Yes. Just copy the function changecolour 4 times as you stated you'd done already.

Comment: I copied it 4 times for the 4 input boxes and just changed the changecolour but the message dose no appear when all are correct

Comment: Eh, sorry, initialize counter to 0 before starting,http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/PTnHf/1/ << working example, answers are 26, 44 and 33

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#questions input').keyup(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == '26') {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
        $(this).attr('correct', 'true');
    } else {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
        $(this).attr('correct', 'false');
    }
    if ($('#questions input[correct="true"]').length == $('#questions input').length) alert("All answers are OK!");

});
```

});​

```
<div id="questions" >
1: <input type="text" id="a1"/><br/>
2: <input type="text" id="a2"/><br/>
3: <input type="text" id="a3"/><br/>
4: <input type="text" id="a4"/><br/>
</div>​
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vash6p/HLF3K/

Answer (score 2):

Keep track of the state of all questions, and interrogate that state in every function:

```
// question 1 is questionState[0], 2 is questionState[1], etc
var questionState = [false, false, false, false];

var allCorrect = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < questionState.length; i++) {
        if (!questionState[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

var changecolour1 = function (textbox) {
    var val = textbox.value;
    if (val == 26) {
        questionState[0] = true;
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        if (allCorrect()) {
            alert('Congratulations!');
        }
    } else {
        questionState[0] = false;
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
};
```

Note you can probably replace all 4 `changecolour` functions with one generic one. This assumes your textboxs have the corresponding IDs:

```
var questions = {
    textbox1: {
        answer: 26,
        state: false
    },
    textbox2: {
        answer: 0,
        state: false
    },
    textbox3: {
        answer: 1,
        state: false
    },
    textbox4: {
        answer: 2,
        state: false
    },
};

var allCorrect = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        if (!questions[i].state) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};

var changecolour = function (textbox) {
    var val = textbox.value;
    if (val == questions[textbox.id].answer) {
        questions[textbox.id].state = true;
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        if (allCorrect()) {
            alert('Congratulations!');
        }
    } else {
        questions[textbox.id].state = false;
        textbox.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
};
```

Comment: Better answer, more elegant solution than mine. I still think the answers shouldn't be held in the page, but depending on the intended audience it may be fine and that isn't relevant to the actual question.

Comment: @RickCalder there's no (ajax-free) way of not having the answers in the page.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. As I said it wasn't really relevant to the question, just a note to the OP. And honestly if it's questions like 1+1 then I doubt the audience is going to be viewing the source lol

Answer (score 0):

hey if you add to every input field a class named boxes you could do something like that..i used jquery for the event stuff.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var Game = {
    correctAnswers: 0,  
    questionCount: undefined,
    addListener: function(boxes){
        this.questionCount = boxes.length;
        var that = this;
        for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
            var item = boxes[i];
            $(item).keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val() == "correct value"){
                    $(this).unbind();
                    that.correctAnswers++;
                    $(this).css({background:'green'});
                    if(that.correctAnswers === that.questionCount){
                        that.gameOver();
                    }
                }else{
                    $(this).css({background:'red'});
                }
            });
        }    
    },
    gameOver: function(){
        alert("You won!");
    }
};
Game.addListener($('.boxes'));
});


<input type="text" class="boxes" />
<input type="text" class="boxes" />
```